# Dropzone.js - remove links not showing even though option selected

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I have this Dropzone:

```
const csrf = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
Dropzone.options.dropzone = {
    maxFilesize: 12,
    acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    timeout: 5000,
    method: "put",
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrf
    }
};
```

The `addRemoveLinks` property is supposed to show a "remove file" link below each thumbnail. But this is not happening. Everything else works - the files are uploaded and saved correctly, the progress bar works, it's all good - but no remove link.

Am I missing something here?

According to the documentation this setting should be all it takes to show the link:

[configuration -> addRemoveLinks](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration)

Answer (score 0):

I'd check your HTML/CSS further. It should be placing an  element with class of dz-remove right at the bottom of the preview  template. I added the flag to my instance and it added it right away, though mine is using previewTemplate and targeting a previewsContainer.